# "Non l'ho visto prima" vs "Non l'avevo visto prima"

Tags: meaning, verbs, difference

What is the difference of meaning between the following sentences?

- Non l'ho visto prima che tu aprissi la porta.
- Non l'avevo visto 
  prima che tu aprissi la porta.

I am familiar with the different usages of the "passato prossimo" and "trapassato prossimo" tenses, but I cannot grasp the difference in this specific context.

Comment: Personally, I would use neither, and go for "l'ho visto solo quando hai aperto la porta" instead.

Comment: +1 Federico. Simpler and more effective

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence doesn't sound right to me even if it is commonly used.
It's implicit that I am saying that I saw in the past but I didn't see before. Then you must use the "trapassato" for the not-seing action.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I don't understand your arguments for affirming that the first sentence doesn't sound right.

Comment: The trapassato is for actions that happened before the action in the main sentence that is already in the past. It's a "double past". Here, the implicit action is I saw, already in the past, then you need a trapassato. To me the key is prima. Anyway, the trapassato is often replaced with a passato in the spoken language and used only when you want to stress the action sequence

Answer (score -1):

There's no difference in meaning. At least if you agree that "I didn't see him before opening the door" and "I hadn't seen him before opening the door" mean the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I wish downvoters would explain why they have downvoted an answer.

Comment: Honestly, me too ;)